# Highchart: display time and date at midnight

Tags: datetime, highcharts, datetime-format

I have a highchart which displayed the last x datapoints I measured.
This can be a few days or some hours.

When I have some hours, I want to display "HH:mm". And when it's midnight I want to display "HH:mm DD.MM.JJJJ".

But when I displayed a few days I only want to display "DD.MM.JJJJ"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
 formatter: function() {
     if (this.axis.tickPositions.length > 2 && (this.axis.tickPositions[1] - this.axis.tickPositions[0]) < (24 * 3600 * 1000)) {
         if (this.dateTimeLabelFormat == format_days) {
             this.dateTimeLabelFormat = format_minutes + "<br />" + format_days;
         }
     }

     return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
```

But I'm sure there is an nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `dateTimeLabelFormats` object to display specific date format on a specific unit.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8gemdjn4/

Comment: but I want two different format for day: one if only days are displayed and one if hours are displayed (and at midnight days)